pyautoguiを用いた画像認識のif分岐
pyautoguiを用いた下記のコードで実行するとdown.pngを表示（elifの条件）させても処理が実行されない（？）
up.pngを表示(ifの条件)した時のみ処理が実行される
処理が実行されていないのかそもそも画像が認識されていないのかも不明
試したこと

そもそも画像が認識されるか確認→個別に試しそれぞれ処理が実行される
画像を他の物に変えて実行→同様にif条件の処理のみ実行される

while True:
try:
    if pgui.locateOnScreen('up.png', confidence=0.9):
       print("up")

    elif pgui.locateOnScreen('down.png', confidence=0.9):
       print("down")
except pgui.ImageNotFoundException:
    pass


ちなみに提示されたソースコードのインデントは質問時の記述/転記間違い等でズレていたりしませんか？ 先頭のwhile True:以外の行はwhileループの中にあると考えられるので、もう一段深いインデントになっているべきだと思うのですが。

pythonはifの判定に成功してその中身を実行するとelifをスキップする仕様です。
そのため"up"が表示された場合に"down"が表示されないのは仕様通りの動作です。
分岐ロジックを変更して"up"も"down"も表示させたい場合は、elifをifに書き換えてください。
